# Why is my PHP application running slower in my production environment?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, apache, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have developed a web application which takes 10 seconds to complete a transaction on php 5.2.17+Apache2.2.8 environment.

After I put them on the production server(Window server 2008+IIS 7+php 5.2.6) it takes 50 seconds to complete the same transaction.

The calculation is based heavily on php, no calculations are done in sql at all.

Did I just mess something up or i this normal for PHP on IIS.

Comment: You don't provide any details as to what said transaction is doing or the spec of the machines, level of traffic on the production web server or production SQL box. At the moment this is like comparing apples and sausages.

Comment: I tested it on my PC(just c2duo with 2gbs of ram web server..) point to db sv,and production sv which is intel xeon with 6gb of ecc ram(in the other word it is a real server spec not pc with colocation) point to same db sv

My PC use 10 sec but sv use 50 sec and the only different thing is I use Apache but sv use IIS :( (no web or db server load for sure)

Comment: I would set both Apache and IIS on the same box and use xdebug to profile PHP script in both environments.

Comment: It could be just about the amount of data processed.

Comment: Where is the database server located? I believe you are stating that both your dev and production servers access the same database server. In that case, is there a difference in the network connection between the servers? How much data is being loaded from the database? Perhaps the production environment has a slow connection to the database but your dev box does not.

Comment: I had similar problem..., but little different. Linux+mysql 5.1.x, php script finished within 5s, but on windows xp+the same version of mysql the script would run 15s. I had the same my own tuned my.cnf on both mysqls... It seems like windows has some performance issue with mysql+tcp connection to the script, or maybe php is slower on windows itself, I don't know. We need more info on your case,maybe the script attached that causes this behaviour? Also do you have the same php.ini on both dev and server machines?

Answer (score 0):

We're all just going to be shooting in the dark, we're missing a lot of detail to help.

Install XHProf: https://github.com/facebook/xhprof in both environments, it will give you detailed information on what PHP is doing, and how long it takes.

A bunch of work has been done to get XHProf running on Windows, though not by Facebook. It shouldn't be a stumbling block. http://www.benjamin-carl.de/howtos/xhprof-php-extension-0-10-0-windows-32nt-compatible-version/